# Unexpected termination and restart of postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We have a postgresql 9.6.14 postgres server, where we run a query which caused a termination of postgresql process and restart of the postgresql process.

We don't know why it happened.

The query runs fine when we query it with another filter value, so I guess it has to do with the amount of data it is querying. But can this really cause a restart of the whole postgres service? So maybe a memory problem?

postgresql.log

> 2019-07-12 17:54:13.487 CEST [6459]: [7-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:
>   server process (PID 11064) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation
>   fault 2019-07-12 17:54:13.487 CEST [6459]: [8-1]
>   user=,db=,app=,client= DETAIL:  Failed process was running:
>
> 2019-07-12 17:54:13.487 CEST [6459]: [9-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:
>   terminating any other active server processes 2019-07-12 17:54:13.488
>   CEST [11501]: [1-1] user=hg,db=test,app=[unknown],client=172.31.0.43
>   WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server
>   process 2019-07-12 17:54:13.488 CEST [11501]: [2-1]
>   user=hg,db=test,app=[unknown],client=172.31.0.43 DETAIL:  The
>   postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current
>   transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally
>   and possibly corrupted shared memory. 2019-07-12 17:54:13.488 CEST
>   [11501]: [3-1] user=hg,db=test,app=[unknown],client=172.31.0.43 HINT: 
>   In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat
>   your command. 2019-07-12 17:54:13.488 CEST [8889]: [2-1]
>   user=hg,db=_test,app=[unknown],client=172.31.0.46 WARNING: 
>   terminating connection because of crash of another server process

```
select stat.*,
         (
              Select
                1
              From
                table1 a, table2 pg
              Where
                a.field_1::Text = stat.field_1::Text And
                a.field_2::Text = stat.field_2::Text And 
                stat.field_3::Text = pg.field_3::Text And 
                a.field_4= pg.field_4
              limit 1
          )
          from table3 stat
          where field_1= 'xyz';
```

Comment: The `terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault` bit from the log suggests that this was an actual crash, as opposed to something like the Postgres or Linux OOM killer killer the process because it was running too high on memory. Is this crash reproducible every single time you run that query with that `where` clause? The Postgres mailing list may be interested in this. It may be either a known bug that has been fixed, or an unknown bug that they would like to investigate.

Comment: Also, anything in the logs that suggest there is corruption in the database?

Comment: It is reproducable in 2 envs with different postgres version - one is 9.6.12 and one 9.6.14- maybe it is executing that in parallel with parallel workes and is consuming to much memory - will check that with the execution plan - is there any other tracing?

Comment: The log output doesn't suggest a memory issue, IMO -- that would usually have a different log message pointing at an OOM killer. Interesting that it is reproducible. Another thing in the logs that may point to corruption other than explicitly saying that are things like the same tables being unable to be vacuumed properly and retries often. What if you copy the data from this table into a new table via a `create table as select *` query? Does it still happen with that new table?

Comment: if would have to created 4-5 tables and 'cause it happens on 2 different system I dont think it is related to corrupt data -  really think it is related to out of mem on one system I saw this entries grep -i 'killed' /var/log/messages-20190714
Jul 12 17:53:36 test-hom-ld03 abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 11064 (postgres) of user 26 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Jul 12 17:59:57 test-hom-ld03 abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 12408 (postgres) of user 26 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
 (which are entries which correspond with the time of the running query and the crash) - but maybe it created a core dump

Comment: Without explicit messages in the logs (system or Postgres) about being out of memory, I'd be somewhat surprised if being out of memory were the case. It seems more likely, IMO, that you've hit a bug that leads to the crash. I'd recommend inquiring on the Postgres mailing list, especially since you have a reproducible scenario.